# Why won't chrome option arguments work in remote web driver? (Selenium 3.11.0)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, chrome-options

I have recently ugpraded to Chrome 65, ChromeDriver 2.37, and Selenium 3.11.0. I am trying to pass in chrome options into our remote web driver for our grid runs so that chrome starts maximized, but I can see from screenshots that the window is NOT getting maximized. Code looks like this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
DriverThread.Value = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), options);
```

We used to have to convert the chrome options to capabilities first but now the remote web driver takes in driver options as a parameter. Does anyone know why this isn't working? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```